# global variables: username_entry1 and password_entry1 are 'not defined'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to have a login system determine whether a user exists in a login system but username_entry1 isn't defined even though I've globalized that variable.

I'm using the IDLE on python 3 and I've determined whether I've globalized username_entry1 (which I should have).

```
def login_verify():

    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()
    username_entry1.delete(0, END)
    password_entry1.delete(0, END)

    list_of_files = os.listdir()
    if username1 == list_of_files:
        file1 = open(username1, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines("\n")
        if password1 in verify:
            print("login sucess")
        else:
            print("password has not been recoginized")

    else:
        print("User not found")

def register():
    #displays register window
    global screen1
    screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen1.title("Register")
    screen1.geometry("300x250")

    global username
    global password
    global username_entry
    global password_entry

    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    #variables to store user & pass
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    Label(screen1, text = "Please enter details below").pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "").pack()

    global username_entry1
    global password_entry1

    #allows the username entry to run
    Label(screen1, text = "Username *").pack()
    username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = username)
    username_entry.pack()

    #allows the password entry to run
    Label(screen1, text = "Password *").pack()
    password_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = password)
    password_entry.pack()

    #allows the register button to run
    Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen1, text = "Register", width = 10, height = 1, command = register_user).pack()
```

I expect my form to say "User not found!"

But error message says...

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Python Projects\LoginSystem.py", line 26, in login_verify
    username_entry1.delete(0, END)
NameError: name 'username_entry1' is not defined
```

Comment: You have not defined the variables anywhere, is this is the full code?

Comment: Did you call `register` before calling `login_verify`?

Comment: This isn't all the code but I've realized that I defined l username_entry1 and password_entry1 into the register function instead of login_verify. But even if I defined the global variables in another function why wouldn't it call the global variables be called?

Comment: The error says you haven't defined `username_entry1`, and there is nowhere in the code you posted where you define `username_entry1`. The error is literally telling you what the problem is.